# Finding percentages in DataFrame columns with a constraint

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame consisting of a location, a type, and a date.

```
d1=sc.parallelize([('a','b1','2015-01-07'), ('a','b2','2015-02-09'),
              ('c', 'b25', '2014-12-01'),('a','b2','2014-09-10'),
              ('c', 'b3','2015-02-21'),('a','b11','2015-09-12'),
              ('a','b7','2014-11-30'), ('c','b26','2014-03-09'),
              ('c', 'b30', '2015-11-28'),('a', 'b5', '2015-03-01'),
              ('c','b25','2015-11-29'),('c', 'b27','2014-01-17'),
              ('c', 'b16','2015-04-01'), ('a', 'b11','2014-01-19'),
              ('a','b7', '2015-09-29'), ('c', 'b12', '2014-08-20')]).toDF(['location',
                'type', 'date_str'])

d2=d1.withColumn('date',d1.date_str.cast('date')).drop('date_str')



|loaction|type|      date|
+--------+----+----------+
|       a|  b1|2015-01-07|
|       a|  b2|2015-02-09|
|       c| b25|2014-12-01|
|       a|  b2|2014-09-10|
|       c|  b3|2015-02-21|
|       a| b11|2015-09-12|
|       a|  b7|2014-11-30|
|       c| b26|2014-03-09|
|       c| b30|2015-11-28|
|       a|  b5|2015-03-01|
|       c| b25|2015-11-29|
|       c| b27|2014-01-17|
|       c| b16|2015-04-01|
|       a| b11|2014-01-19|
|       a|  b7|2015-09-29|
|       c| b12|2014-08-20|
+--------+----+----------+
```

I want to get the percentage of types for a given location in 2014 who also appeared in the same location in 2015.

In this case there are 3 different types in location 'a' in 2014,
b2,b7, and b11. In 2015 there are  5 different types in 
location 'a', b1,b2,b11,b5, and b7. So out out of the three types
who were in 2014, all three were also in 2015,i.e, 100% ( 3 of 3) 
in 2015.

For location 'c', there were four types in 2014, b25, b26, b27, and b12. 
In 2015 there were three types b30, b25, b16. The number of types in 2014 
who were also seen in 2015 is 25% (1 of 4).

I am trying to get back a DataFrame that looks like this

```
|location|percent_retained|
+--------+----------------+
|       a|               1|
|       c|             .25|
+--------+----------------+
```

I can do a groupBy to get raw counts for each year, but that doesn't help because I only want to know the number of types in 2015 who also appeared in 2014.

```
d2=d2.withColumn('year', F.year(d2.date))
d2.groupBy('location', 'year').agg('type':'count')
```

I'm using Spark 1.5 so I can't pivot the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the year as you did, then group by `location` and `type`. Then you can map the list of years (per location, per type) and apply the logic you want.

For what I can understand, you can have one year, or both years. You can just translate it to a flag like "retained", "just-2014", "just-2015" and do the rest of computation from there.